Hiding physical hardware changes from VM guest
I'm running a Windows guest under Proxmox VE 8.2 (on Debian 12) and would like to hide information about the underlying physical hardware from the guest.
Motivation
I have paid full price for a perpetual licence for some Inventory Management software which has gone "end of life" for support and the vendor has decided to switch off their licence server. They have issued me an offline access certificate but the catch is that:

the certificate is invalidated if their Windows application (on my machine) detects changes to its underlying hardware.
if I reinstall the app, I'm not aware of any mechanism for me to import a previously issued certificate.

To reduce the chances of the app detecting major hardware changes I have installed the app on a Windows virtual machine. (The host is KVM on Linux.) I would like the freedom to migrate the VM to different physical machines, upgrade hardware on the PC running the hypervisor etc, whenever necessary.
Hardware as Perceived by the VM
I am ignorant of the algorithm used by the app to detect hardware changes, but I suspect it may look at things such as:

CPU serial number
network interface MAC addresses
BIOS strings
Hard drive UUID

Some of that information (e.g. the CPU information as seen in Windows System Information app) seems to be taken from the VM host and passed through to the guest by the hypervisor.
Can you tell me which Proxmox (or Qemu/KVM) settings I should adjust to hide (or override, or freeze) the hardware identifiers visible to the VM guest?

In Proxmox VE you can set a subset of Qemu "identifiers", including these:

Hide a real identity of the processor by showing not a "host" CPU but an emulated CPU with reduced flags to the VM. That is controlled by the CPU selection dialog, available as Hardware → CPU Settings in the GUI
Set up various serial numbers, which is available as Options → SMBIOS settings (type 1) in the GUI. By default there is one randomly generated UUID, but you can fill much more, making it to look like SMBIOS looks in a branded PC. In the VM these identifiers are typically available as DMI information; in Linux we use dmidecode utility to view that, I can't suggest a comprehensive utility for Windows.

Qemu is able to set up various data for other virtual devices, but Proxmox doesn't expose this possibility through its tools. You can still use that by manually editing the VM configuration file, available as /etc/pve/qemu-server/<VMID>.conf; it's format is pretty self-descriptive. For example, you can add a serial number to your hard disk as described here: just append ,serial=524352134 to your drive definition, which is scsiN or virtioN or, if you're ignorant enough to not appreciate performance benefits VirtIO brings, sataN or ideN.
You can also add arbitrary arguments to the Qemu command line using args:; it's value will be simply appended to the generated command line. It was the way I've added virtual floppy or virtual USB flash devices to the VMs in the past, for the software licensing that relied upon the "key floppy" or "key flash".
Be careful; editing via GUI afterwards won't erase your args:, but it may erase things that you're added to other items. Also, be aware that if you refer to outside files in your custom additions, these files won't be considered for the standard Proxmox backup; I've caught into that loophole once when my virtual floppy image, referenced from args:, wasn't backed up together with the virtual machine. You have to backup these files separately, yourself.
You can see what command line it is generating based on the configuration file by running qm showcmd <VMID>; that will make you better understand how the Qemu command line looks like and how the configuration file is interpreted.

Great write-up, thankyou. I tried modifying many of these IDs using ProxMox and was able to see the changes reflected inside the guest using DMI Decode for Windows.
I'm pleased to report that despite these changes, none of them seemed to trigger a hardware-changed exception in the application software. The next test would be to move the guest to a completely different VM host.
